# Solr Search Using Susnpot Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, sunspot

I am currently using the sunspot gem to implement full text search in my rails application. Queries on my website through Sunspot/Solr are working and returning the proper results. However, when I attempt to make a query using the Solr admin page, I am having a hard time displaying results. Using the query string `*:*` I can display all the results contained in my indexed database, but  I cannot make a proper query. If I try to make a query using a string other than `*:*`, such as `test`, no results are returned and I am left with:

```
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">21</int>
    <lst name="params">
      <str name="explainOther"/>
      <str name="fl">*,score</str>
      <str name="indent">on</str>
      <str name="start">0</str>
      <str name="q">test</str>
      <str name="hl.fl"/>
      <str name="qt"/>
      <str name="wt"/>
      <str name="fq"/>
      <str name="version">2.2</str>
      <str name="rows">10</str>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0" maxScore="0.0"/>
</response>
```

Making the same query using the string: `test` on the actual rails application returns over 100 results.

How can I make queries in the Solr admin page return the same items as the queries made in the rails app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Jayendra's answer a bit (which is essentially right):

> If I try to make a query using a string other than `*:*`, such as `test`, no results are returned…

That query is being run against the `defaultSearchField`, which is `text` by default in Sunspot. Confusingly, however, Sunspot isn't putting anything into that `text` field, so your search results are correct. There are no documents with the term `test` in their `text` field because there are no documents with a `text` field.

You may have, say, a `title_text` field. You can query that field directly with `q=title_text:test`.

You can also mimic Sunspot's queries: use the DisMax query parser, explicitly specifying the fields to query in `qf`. This is helpful if you want to query against multiple text fields, not to mention receive the other benefits of DisMax: `q=test&defType=dismax&qf=title_text+body_text`

Also, Sunspot logs its queries to `development.log` which is a good place to look for examples.

Answer (score 3):

`*:*` would basically search for all on all fields, and hence matches all documents.

What field are you searching on from the Rails application ?
By default, queries through Solr admin are fired on the default search field (schema.xml).

```
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
```

Try to change your query fired on solr to the specific field e.g. `q=some_field:test` and check if results are returned.