# Rails Sunspot solr search returns multiple entries of the same record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I'm using Sunspot solr search in Rails application to list Users.

Users Controller :

```
def index
  @users = User.search { 
    fulltext params[:search]
    paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
  }.results
end
```

User Model :

```
searchable do
  text :email

  text :user_profile do
    user_profile.name
  end
end
```

Whenever I update any User, the search results in two entries of the same record, visiting both will take me to the same record.

```
/users/1
```

Each time I need to run

```
rake sunspot:reindex[,User]
```

to fix this.

Is there a way where it returns only one entry, even after updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be really hard to find. But here are some options:

1) Make sure that you have 2 indexed records. Here some advices how to debug: [Debugging Solr search queries on Sunspot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714455/debugging-solr-search-queries-on-sunspot)

2) Look at config/sunspot.yml in order to see callbacks settings [Github sunspot example](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/327c7e4e2d3a9ad8351e8941d646e37088224341/sunspot_rails/generators/sunspot/templates/sunspot.yml) There should be auto_remove_callback setting