# SOLR 502 error when making requests in parallel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, lucene, sunspot

Our stack uses SOLR (via the Ruby sunspot gem). We also have a script that fires thousands of search terms at SOLR to see which ones have a good score and eliminate the others. The script was setup to run with 24 threads but many request fail with a `url failed. HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway`.

Apparently it used to run through from start to finish without problems - but this was before I worked on the project. Now, the only way it works is with one thread but that takes too long. Because I've never seen it work I'm not aware of what is causing the problem.

My question is; what steps can I take to debug this and fix? Thanks

- Ruby version: 2.3.1
- Sunspot version: 2.2.7

[EDIT]

Full error:

```
Url failed: https://example.com/solr/example-sunspot/select?q=%2B%22Boat%22%20%2B%22Best%22%20%2B%22Plush%22%20%2B%22Melissa%20%26%20Doug%22%20%2Bname_texts%3A%22Toy%22%7E4%5E4%20-name_texts%3A%22wardrobe%22%20-name_texts%3A%22cupboard%22%20-name_texts%3A%22drawers%22%20-name_texts%3A%22box%22%20-name_texts%3A%22footmuff%22%20-name_texts%3A%22buggy%22%20-name_texts%3A%22step%20stool%22%20-name_texts%3A%22sleeping%20bag%22%20-name_texts%3A%22bouncer%22%20-name_texts%3A%22bedding%22%20-name_texts%3A%22cot%22%20-name_texts%3A%22changing%20bag%22%20-name_texts%3A%22room%20set%22%20-name_texts%3A%22book%22%20-name_texts%3A%22feeding%22%20-name_texts%3A%22storage%22&fq=type%3AExternalProduct&fq=available_b%3Atrue&fl=*+score&wt=json&defType=edismax&qf=name_texts+description_text+non_stem_name_text&pf=name_texts%5E2.0&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true&rows=1&scoreDist=true (HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway)
```

/var/log/solr/stderr.log:

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to flush writer,
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.flush(QuietWriter.java:59)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:324)
at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:276)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.log(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:601)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.log(JettyAwareLogger.java:620)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.info(JettyAwareLogger.java:314)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:74)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1259)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1182)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
```

/var/log/nginx/error.log:

```
2017/03/15 11:44:10 [error] 1219#0: *10797360 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 95.146.105.87, server: solr-production.cahootsy.com, request: "GET /solr/caho
otsy-sunspot/select?q=%2B%22Toddler%22%20%22Cute%22%5E4%20%2B%22Comfort%22%20%2B%22Ragtales%22%20%2Bname_texts%3A%22Teddy%20Bear%22%7E4%5E4%20-name_texts%3A%22lingerie%22%20-name_texts%3A%22wallpaper%22%2
0-name_texts%3A%22box%22%20-name_texts%3A%22dress%22%20-name_texts%3A%22quilt%22%20-name_texts%3A%22acrylic%22%20-name_texts%3A%22ribbon%22%20-name_texts%3A%22footmuff%22%20-name_texts%3A%22buggy%22%20-na
me_texts%3A%22step%20stool%22%20-name_texts%3A%22sleeping%20bag%22%20-name_texts%3A%22bouncer%22%20-name_texts%3A%22changing%20bag%22%20-name_texts%3A%22room%20set%22%20-name_texts%3A%22feeding%22%20-name_texts%3A%22storage%22&fq=type%3AExternalProduct&fq=available_b%3Atrue&fl=*+score&wt=json&defType=edismax&qf=name_texts+description_text+non_stem_name_text&pf=name_texts%5E2.0&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true&rows=1&scoreDist=true HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/cahootsy-sunspot/select?q=%2B%22Toddler%22%20%22Cute%22%5E4%20%2B%22Comfort%22%20%2B%22Ragtales%22%20%2Bname_texts%3A%22Teddy%20Bear%22%7E4%5E4%20-name_texts%3A%22lingerie%22%20-name_texts%3A%22wallpaper%22%20-name_texts%3A%22box%22%20-name_texts%3A%22dress%22%20-name_texts%3A%22quilt%22%20-name_texts%3A%22acrylic%22%20-name_texts%3A%22ribbon%22%20-name_texts%3A%22footmuff%22%20-name_texts%3A%22buggy%22%20-name_texts%3A%22step%20stool%22%20-name_texts%3A%22sleeping%20bag%22%20-name_texts%3A%22bouncer%22%20-name_texts%3A%22changing%20bag%22%20-name_texts%3A%22room%20set%22%20-name_texts%3A%22feeding%22%20-name_texts%3A%22storage%22&fq=type%3AExternalProduct&fq=available_b%3Atrue&fl=*+score&wt=json&defType=edismax&qf=name_texts+description_text+non_stem_name_text&pf=name_texts%5E2.0&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true&rows=1&scoreDist=true", host: "solr-production.cahootsy.com"
```

/var/log/solr/stdout.log:

```
908831 [qtp24433162-47] INFO org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 4803295 (1562039497978281984)]} 0 1 908899 [qtp24433162-55] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 2626369 (1562039498050633728)]} 0 0
908947 [qtp24433162-13] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 3634992 (1562039498100965376)]} 0 0
908971 [qtp24433162-34] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 2626370 (1562039498126131200)]} 0 0
909008 [qtp24433162-49] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 3631728 (1562039498164928512)]} 0 1
909047 [qtp24433162-75] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 2626371 (1562039498205822976)]} 0 1
909102 [qtp24433162-39] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 3645291 (1562039498263494656)]} 0 0
909152 [qtp24433162-18] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 2626372 (1562039498315923456)]} 0 0
909202 [qtp24433162-41] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 3632336 (1562039498368352256)]} 0 0
909252 [qtp24433162-36] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 2626373 (1562039498420781056)]} 0 0
909308 [qtp24433162-35] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 3643432 (1562039498479501312)]} 0 0
909363 [qtp24433162-20] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 3631978 (1562039498537172992)]} 0 0
909415 [qtp24433162-51] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 2626374 (1562039498591698944)]} 0 0
909467 [qtp24433162-66] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 2626375 (1562039498646224896)]} 0 0
909527 [qtp24433162-54] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 3646560 (1562039498709139456)]} 0 0
909552 [qtp24433162-30] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? UnInverted multi-valued field {field=category_ids_im,memSize=21348590,tindexSize=178,time=148,phase1=141,nTerms=1293,bigTerms=1,termInstances=4492323,uses=0}
909566 [qtp24433162-30] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? UnInverted multi-valued field {field=collection_ids_im,memSize=20225677,tindexSize=470,time=13,phase1=9,nTerms=4121,bigTerms=0,termInstances=17715,uses=0}
909598 [qtp24433162-71] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 2626376 (1562039498783588352)]} 0 0
909623 [qtp24433162-65] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 3634957 (1562039498809802752)]} 0 0
909657 [qtp24433162-60] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 2626377 (1562039498845454336)]} 0 0
909710 [qtp24433162-38] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 3631099 (1562039498899980288)]} 0 1
909760 [qtp24433162-44] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 2626378 (1562039498953457664)]} 0 0
909803 [qtp24433162-42] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 3635001 (1562039498998546432)]} 0 0
909869 [qtp24433162-46] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 3635754 (1562039499067752448)]} 0 0
909923 [qtp24433162-64] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 2626379 (1562039499123326976)]} 0 1
909944 [qtp24433162-30] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? UnInverted multi-valued field {field=community_ids_ims,memSize=20188632,tindexSize=44,time=10,phase1=7,nTerms=6,bigTerms=0,termInstances=2522,uses=0}
909952 [qtp24433162-67] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 2626380 (1562039499154784256)]} 0 0
909974 [qtp24433162-30] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? UnInverted multi-valued field {field=inferred_community_ids_ims,memSize=20188920,tindexSize=44,time=29,phase1=26,nTerms=6,bigTerms=3,termInstances=122033,uses=0}
909975 [qtp24433162-30] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/select params={f.inferred_community_ids_ims.facet.mincount=1&facet.field=category_ids_im&facet.field=collection_ids_im&facet.field=colour_s&facet.field=brand_ss&facet.field=retailer_ss&facet.field=community_ids_ims&facet.field=inferred_community_ids_ims&f.retailer_ss.facet.mincount=0&start=0&f.category_ids_im.facet.mincount=0&fq=type:ExternalProduct&fq=is_retailer_b:true&fq=-retailer_normalized_s:(asos)&fq=available_b:true&fq=category_ids_im:(2304)&sort=cahootsy_score_i+desc,+random_1632017+asc&rows=16&f.brand_ss.facet.mincount=0&f.community_ids_ims.facet.mincount=1&q=*:*&f.collection_ids_im.facet.mincount=1&f.category_ids_im.facet.limit=-1&wt=ruby&facet=true&f.colour_s.facet.mincount=0} hits=18140 status=0 QTime=636
910006 [qtp24433162-29] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 3630950 (1562039499211407360)]} 0 0
910048 [qtp24433162-28] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 2626381 (1562039499255447552)]} 0 0
910098 [qtp24433162-58] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 3634841 (1562039499307876352)]} 0 0
910167 [qtp24433162-63] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=ruby} {add=[ExternalProduct 2626382 (1562039499380228096)]} 0 0
910211 [qtp24433162-59] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] webapp=/solr path=/select params={f.inferred_community_ids_ims.facet.mincount=1&facet.field=category_ids_im&facet.field=collection_ids_im&facet.field=colour_s&facet.field=brand_ss&facet.field=retailer_ss&facet.field=community_ids_ims&facet.field=inferred_community_ids_ims&f.retailer_ss.facet.mincount=0&start=0&f.category_ids_im.facet.mincount=0&fq=type:ExternalProduct&fq=is_retailer_b:true&fq=retailer_normalized_s:(asos)&fq=available_b:true&fq=category_ids_im:(2304)&sort=cahootsy_score_i+desc,+random_1632017+asc&rows=6&f.brand_ss.facet.mincount=0&f.community_ids_ims.facet.mincount=1&q=*:*&f.collection_ids_im.facet.mincount=1&f.category_ids_im.facet.limit=-1&wt=ruby&facet=true&f.colour_s.facet.mincount=0} hits=15791 status=0 QTime=5
```

[Edit 2]

I tried tailing the /var/log/solr/stdout.log whilst reproducing the problem and found this in the logs:

```
8846 [commitScheduler-9-thread-1] WARN  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? [cahootsy-sunspot] Error opening new searcher. exceeded limit of maxWarmingSearchers=2, try again later.
8848 [commitScheduler-9-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.solr.update.CommitTracker  ? auto commit error...:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher. exceeded limit of maxWarmingSearchers=2, try again later.
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1672)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:607)
    at org.apache.solr.update.CommitTracker.run(CommitTracker.java:216)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714455/debugging-solr-search-queries-on-sunspot#9202056

Comment: I don't think it is duplicate - this question is about parallel requests in particular. Could you please be more specific - which errors actually on Solr side? Can it happen so that it is just due to Jetty's / Tomcat's thread-pool size - and after certain saturation single server is not capable to serve lots of requests? In that case you just need to set-up several machines and throttle your payload appropriately.

Comment: Hi @PaulVasilev, thanks for your reply. I've updated the question with some more detailed log information. Does that help? I think it could be due to the server not being capable of serving the number of threads

Comment: Well, the message clearly states: `No space left on device` and it is thrown from Log4J. Which means you don't have free space for your logging engine (check your hard drive disk space). I'm not sure whether this could cause the issue with Solr, being queried in parallel - let me double-check. Btw, do you have other ERRORs / Exceptions in your logs?

Comment: Thanks @PaulVasilev - that's true. You were right, disk space was full. However, I free'd up some space but i'm still getting the 502 issue. Sure. Which log do you think I should check?

Comment: I mean the actual ERROR / Exception on Solr side which causes the 502 to be retrieved.

Comment: @PaulVasilev I've added tail of the `/var/log/solr/stdout.log`. Is that helpful?

Comment: @cahootsyquestion well yeah, that's much better :) but it doesn't contain any ERRORs / Exceptions - I bet what we need here is to: kick-off `tail -f` and try to reproduce the issue, like start hitting Solr from client side with many requests in parallel. Eventually log should catch some errors

Comment: @PaulVasilev - I just tried what you said and I found this: `34141 [commitScheduler-9-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.solr.update.CommitTracker  ? auto commit error...:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher. exceeded limit of maxWarmingSearchers=2, try again later.` Looks like it could be related. I'll update the question with the full stacktrace.

Comment: Does this exception has `cause` part? Looks like the culprit is underneath :)

Comment: I can't see anything above or below the log that looks interesting. Would it be labeled `cause`? I tried searching the log file for `cause` but couldn't find anything.

Comment: actually I'm not quite sure it is directly related to your problem.. `org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit` means somebody tried to issue `commit` to close opened indexing transaction.. are you sure there are no stack-traces of the query-time related errors?

Comment: Hi @PaulVasilev. To be honest I'm not sure - how do I query time-related errors? Will it be in the log files? Please excuse my lack of SOLR knowledge!

Comment: That's fine, dude ;) Well, the rule and sequence of troubleshooting is to: (1) make problem reproducible (able to make requests in parallel to observe the problem - logs or messages or incorrect behavior) - ideally it is some hand-written test. (2) isolate the problem as much as possible (if your problem spans across different tiers it won't help a lot. Ideally you should break down your request into baby steps - like "Request From UI" -> "Apache Proxy" -> "Solr's Tomcat/Jetty" --> "Dispatcher" --> "Solr's internals". After that you can eliminate parts which are not erroneous like one by one).

Comment: It can happen so, that the problem is not related to SOLR at all - you may encounter problems before hitting `Solr`-tier in this end-to-end break-down. Thinking out it could be: authorization issues, wrong Apache Rewrite module rules, network issues. This is what you will get after making `reproducibility` + `isolation` of the problem.
Just another angle to consider - usually Solr's default logs are located under `./server/logs/solr.log` or `./example/cloud/node1/logs/solr.log` or something.

Comment: Btw, dude I see you url-encode ampersands / equals-signs in your request: `&` -> `%26`, `=` -> `%3D`. I don't think you should encode it - it is part of HTTP contract. Maybe that is the issue - please check. So the request should look rather like that: `https://example.com/solr/example-sunspot/select?q=...here+is+lots+of+urlencoded+stuff...&fq=type%3AExternalProduct&fq=available_b%3Atrue&fl=*+score&wt=json&defType=edismax&qf=name_texts+description_text+non_stem_name_text&pf=name_texts%5E2.0&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true&rows=1&scoreDist=true`

Comment: Thanks @PaulVasilev will attempt this approach and get back to you on progress